# Asp textbox with textmode=date cannot validate greater than current date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, types, textbox

I have a asp textbox with the type=DateTimeLocal. I am trying to validate it it to make sure that it's datetime value is greater than the current datetime. I have tried compare validators loading values both in aspx and vb(server) side. I have tried range validators and custom validators. My Custom validators never trigger. Range and Compare always returns that is is invalid.

How can I validate that the text entered in the textbox with the type=DateTimeLocal provided is greater than current date time?

**ASPX Page**

```
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtStartDate" TextMode="DateTimeLocal" runat="server" type="date"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStartDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Date is required" Text="*"
                ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ValidationGroup="AddEvent"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RangeValidator ID="rgvStartDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Date must be a date after the current Date"
                text="*" ValidationGroup="AddEvent" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" Type="Date"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

===================================

**Back End**

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    rgvStartDate.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1.0).ToString("d")
    rgvStartDate.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(100.0).ToString("d")

End Sub
```

=====================================
**Solution**

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="txtStartDate">Start Date:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">

            <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtStartDate" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStartDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Date is required" Text="*"
                ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ValidationGroup="AddEvent"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RangeValidator ID="rgvStartDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Date must be a date after the current Date"
                text="*" ValidationGroup="AddEvent" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" Type="Date"></asp:RangeValidator>

        </div>
    </div>

           <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="txtStartDateTime">Start Time:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">

            <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtStartDateTime" TextMode="Time" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStartDateTime" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Time is required" Text="*"
                ControlToValidate="txtStartDateTime" ValidationGroup="AddEvent"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Originally I had the time and date both inside the same textbox, however this caused my validations not to work. The solution was to make a separate textbox for time, and then let date be by itself. Then when you go to add, you can put the date and time together.

- `<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtStartDate"
  TextMode="DateTimeLocal" runat="server" type="date"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Hi! Try to add some relevant part of your code. Check if you set CausesValidation="true" when submits the forms... etc.

Comment: Why not you set the minimum value of the range validator with the current date? Have you tried anything??

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the minimum range of the validator programmatically on Page_Load. You also have to set the minimum and maximum values of the validator with some dummy formats (Min - 1/1/1999 , Max - 1/1/2045).

This will set the minimum value of the validator with the date you want.One day plus with the current date.

```
DateRangeValidator.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1.0).ToString("d");
```

This should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This was one of the attempts I made. The thing that now occurs is every date enter is invalid. I believe it may be due to the fact I am using a textbox with the type attribute=DateTimeLocal. This means it appears on the page like this

dd/mm/yyyy --:-- -- <br> Could the time portion be causing issues?

Comment: Yes, I think the time portion is causing the error. Remove the time portion and use the Date only. It should solve your problem.

Comment: If this is the answer you expect then it should be marked as answer.